# Contar valores duplicados em lista

Tags: java, android, lista

Tenho um `ArrayList` com vários números dentro dele. Preciso identificar quantas vezes cada número aparece e, depois, eliminar as redundâncias. Consegui eliminar redundâncias, mas estou tendo grandes problemas na hora de identificar quantos tem de cada um.

O que conseguir fazer até agora:

```
private List<Calculos> RemoverDuplicados()
{
    aux = new ArrayList<Calculos>();
    ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int[] intArray = new int[aux.size()];

    //separa os cálculos repetidos e envia para a lista auxiliar;
    for(Calculos i : calculosItems)
    {
        //se a variável 'ids' não tiver o valor do ID do produto, eu adiciono aqui
        if(!ids.contains(Integer.valueOf(i.getId_produto())))
        {
            aux.add(i);
            ids.add(Integer.valueOf(i.getId_produto()));
        }
    }

    for(Calculos i : aux){
        Log.d(TAG,"ID: " + i.getId_produto() + " possui: ? calculos");;
    }

    return aux;
}
```

**Estes são os valores (que estão dentro do banco de dados):**

```
2
1
2
2
2
2
2
1
3
3
3
3
4
5
5
6
6
6
```

**O output atual é:**

```
D/﹕ ~~ Calculos depois:
05-16 19:48:23.586  28643-28643/com.financeiro.coolkey.financeiro_2 D/﹕ ID: 2 possui: ? calculos
05-16 19:48:23.586  28643-28643/com.financeiro.coolkey.financeiro_2 D/﹕ ID: 1 possui: ? calculos
05-16 19:48:23.586  28643-28643/com.financeiro.coolkey.financeiro_2 D/﹕ ID: 3 possui: ? calculos
05-16 19:48:23.586  28643-28643/com.financeiro.coolkey.financeiro_2 D/﹕ ID: 4 possui: ? calculos
05-16 19:48:23.586  28643-28643/com.financeiro.coolkey.financeiro_2 D/﹕ ID: 5 possui: ? calculos
05-16 19:48:23.586  28643-28643/com.financeiro.coolkey.financeiro_2 D/﹕ ID: 6 possui: ? calculos
```

No lugar do `?` ele deveria me mostrar o número de cálculos, por exemplo: `ID 1 possui 2 calculos`.

Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Como você consegue remover as duplicatas então conhece os valores duplicados, certo? Se sim, para verificar a frequência de cada valor veja [`#frequency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)), talvez possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: Sim, bom amigo. Eu encontrei este Frequency nas minhas pesquisas, mas fiquei confuso por que eu não sei aonde exatamente no código deveria adicioná-lo e quais parâmetros. Por exemplo, eu sei que tenho 6 IDS, neste caso. Eu gostaria de ter 1 array que eu pudesse armazenar o número de frequências de cada ID, mas não consigo pensar numa lógica para isso :(

Comment: Você quer, por exemplo, ter um mapa que contenha a quantidade de cada ID? Ou seja, num mapa com chave e valor inteiros, para a chave sendo o ID 2 ter o valor 6?

Comment: Exatamente, meu caro! Fico feliz que tenha entendido meu problema, tenho dificuldades em esclarecer as coisas, hehe. :)

Comment: Certo, já posto para você e você me diz se é isto que precisa.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado pela consideração!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo do postado em sua pergunta você conhece as duplicatas então para verificar a frequência de cada valor você pode usar [`#frequency()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,java.lang.Object)) de [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

Você disse nos comentários que precisa armazenar a quantidade de IDs para cada ID. Uma forma de fazer isto é usando um mapa em que a chave (key) seria o id e o valor seria a quantidade.

Um exemplo, iniciando uma lista com os IDs que você possui seria este:

```
final List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6);

final Map<Integer, Integer> idQuantidade = new HashMap<>();

idQuantidade.put(1, Collections.frequency(ids, 1));
idQuantidade.put(2, Collections.frequency(ids, 2));
idQuantidade.put(6, Collections.frequency(ids, 6));
```

Então, para imprimir cada valor teríamos algo assim:

```
final String format = "ID: %d possui: %d calculos";
final Set<Integer> chaves = idQuantidade.keySet(); // as chaves são os ids
for (final Integer chave : chaves) {
    System.out.println(String.format(format, chave, idQuantidade.get(chave)));
}
```

Que irá exibir o seguinte:

```
ID: 1 possui: 2 calculos
ID: 2 possui: 6 calculos
ID: 6 possui: 3 calculos
```

Uma outra forma, em Java 8+, seria utilizar o método [`#compute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) de [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> idQuantidade = new HashMap<>();

ids.forEach(id -> idQuantidade.compute(id, (chave, valor) -> (valor == null ? 1 : valor + 1)));
```

Desta forma, iteramos os valores da lista e vamos preenchendo o mapa, usando o id como chave e o valor igual a `1` quando não existir chave -> valor no maps ou incrementando em `1` sempre que já existir como chave um id. A impressão de cada valor seria algo assim:

```
idQuantidade.forEach((chave, valor) -> System.out.println(String.format("ID: %d possui: %d calculos", chave, idQuantidade.get(chave))));
```

Que irá exibir o seguinte:

```
ID: 1 possui: 2 calculos
ID: 2 possui: 6 calculos
ID: 3 possui: 4 calculos
ID: 4 possui: 1 calculos
ID: 5 possui: 2 calculos
ID: 6 possui: 3 calculos
```

Você também poderá ter uma estrutura de dados própria, fica a seu critério, depende de seu contexto.

Comment: Cara, você é um gênio, muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente, brother!!!

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que você tem os valores em um BD, por que não obter esses dados já na forma que pretende?

Assumindo que a sua classe de acesso ao BD é `db` e que o nome da coluna que pretende saber o número de ocorrências é `produtoId`, o seguinte código obtém um *Cursor* com a soma das ocorrências de `produtoId` e escreve um *log* por cada um:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT produtoId, count(*) FROM nomeDaSuaTabela GROUP BY produroId", null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Log.d(TAG,"ID: " + cursor.getInt(0) + " possui: cursor.getInt(1) calculos");
}
cursor.close();
```